How can I update a Jax-RS query parameter using a ContainerRequestFilter?
I am working on a JAX-RS resource and one of my GET methods has a query parameter, let's call it "foo". Our API design has deemed that the value can be comma separated or specified multiple times:
So the following URIs are valid:
Example 1:
/api/items?foo=bar&foo=baz

Example 2:
/api/items?foo=bar,baz

I know that I can iterate through foo in the method body and split them up if they are comma separated. Ideally, I would like the values to come in the method body pre-split.
@GET
@Path("/items")
fun listItems(QueryParam("foo") foo: List<String>) {
    // I would like foo to have no comma separated values here.
}

I read that I can use a ContainerRequestFilter to modify some of the request data however when I try to update the query parameter I get an error saying that the query parameter property is immutable.
@Provider
class FooQueryParamFilter : ContainerRequestFilter {

    override fun filter(requestContext: ContainerRequestContext) {
        val queryParameters = requestContext.uriInfo.queryParameters
        var additionalProperties = queryParameters["additional-properties"]
        if (!additionalProperties.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            queryParameters["additional-properties"] = additionalProperties
                    .flatMap { it.split(",") }
                    .filter { it.isNotBlank() && it.isNotEmpty() }
        }
    }
}

How can I get around this error? Is it possible to modify the query parameters using the ContainerRequestFilter or another interface?
